# ArcGIS - Cell Content Deletion

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, attribute-table, erase

I have a really simple question I can't find the answer to. I'm looking to delete a range of values from an attribute table in ArcGIS 10. I'm looking for a quick way to delete about 3000 records. The idea is to have some blank records so when I do a dissolve in order to form polygons, the 3000 tiny polygons are no longer there and only larger polygons are dissolved to form bigger polygons on the basis of the same column contents.

So I basically have 2 questions:

1. How do I delete a range of 3000 records from the attribute table, by FID range or any other efficient method?
2. Will blank cell contents prevent records from being included in a dissolve?

(Or 3., is there any way of creating a conditional dissolve which avoids a range of records according to FID/other column value?)

Comment: Do you want to use the attributes from the large polyon, and ignore the attributes from the smaller ones?

Comment: The dissolve tool, like any geo-processing tool, will honour an existing selection so if you sub-selected your data only those will be considered by the dissolve criteria.  You also seem to be mixing terminology?  You say you want to delete records then you refer to blank cells. When you talk about deleting are you actually talking about setting row values to nothing? You could do this, I would personally delete them from the dataset but if you choose to keep them then select everything else.

Comment: Matthew: Yes, the small polygons are additional ones - when I tried a default dissolve with all the small ones remained - I'd like to omit them from the dissolve.

Comment: Hornbydd: I've created a new column populated with data from another column. I thought I might have to delete the cells belonging to polygons that I didn't want, from that column. From what you're saying I can either select the ones I want and dissolve with them selected, or delete them from the dataset entirely. I wasn't sure what the quickest way to delete/set row values to nothing was. But I'll try selecting the records first and see if it works. Thanks again -

Comment: Hornbydd - I've just done the dissolve with selected records. It worked - Thanks! Unfortunately I've discovered that where the tiny polygons were I've now got gaps. I'm sure there's an easy way to fill them in - I've heard there's a Fill Hole tool but I don't seem to have it (have checked). There are too many to do by hand. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I think there is an existing GIS-SE question with answer on how to fill holes in donut polygons but if not I recommend asking as a new question rather than as a comment.

Comment: Thanks PolyGeo - Although I had searched, I hadn't searched enough. I found a post which mentioned the Eliminate tool. I selected the unwanted holes and ran it - it worked perfectly.

Comment: It sounds like all is resolved now so hopefully you are in a position to write up an Answer to your own Question that you can subsequently Accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eliminate tool worked perfectly - I found out it existed here:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/12992/21121

It eliminated all the unwanted polygons from the attribute table too, as well as visually deleting them (something which the dissolve and Union tools hadn't managed to do).

Thanks all, especially PolyGeo who suggested a check gis stack exchange more carefully for potential answers.